# Custom Page Builder

Tags: magento2, wysiwyg, page-builder

There is page builder for admin scope area, I want to create or use it for different scope area named as vendor.
Any suggestions on what should I do I should create the new one or I can use the admin scope page builder?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is rather unclear. Are you talking about a product attribute of type "Page Builder"? Please elaborate further what you try to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear
But may I suggest using this Page Builder instead https://github.com/Goomento/PageBuilder It's a Free and Opening Source

This extension come up with

- Drag and Drop visual editor
- Section, Pages, Templates control
- Import, Export content
- Undo, Redo, Duplicate, and more ...
- History, Revision management
- Reuse as page, template
- Widgets hub management
- Adaptability in any store
- High speed optimize
- Add custom CSS
- Responsive design